# Facebook chat icon status

Tags: facebook

In Facebook my friends see me with a light grey colored cellphone icon next to my name (in Facebook's messenger). Is this icon always on, even if my phone is off? Is it on if Facebook is running in the background, is it on if the app is actually running as an active app? Does it turn green if I am using the app actively (focused)?